# How long do browsers store downloaded assets in a single session

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to preLoad data from the server so that it will be immediately available when I call for it. The data is stored in a file called "data.json".

At first, I thought to save `data.json` to an object and reference it when I need it.

However, depending on the user's actions it may take a while before I need the data that this object has stored. So memory management becomes a bit of a concern as the object is quiet large (~5 mb).

My question is, when I call for `data.json` via ajax, does the browser internally "cache" this file for the duration of the website session.

Meaning, if I called for the file via ajax again after calling for it already, the browser would instantly get the file from its own internal memory instead of going back to the server?

If so it seems it would be wasteful saving an extra copy of this file in JavaScript. However, I can't find any information/standards about this online.

So in short, do I need to save the downloaded file to an object? Or is it safe to let browsers handle this internally?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: @SLaks So caching in a live session uses the same cache methods as long term caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different types of "cache" in play here. It sounds like you're asking "How long does the browser's JavaScript engine keep an object in memory" and the answer is "As long as there's a reference to it."

The browser's (HTTP) cache, on the other hand, lives longer; an entry may live for days or weeks or years, depending on the available space, the freshness headers on the response, etc.

For a scenario like you've described, you probably want to prefetch the JSON to a local cache file, then load that cache file into JavaScript only as needed.

Comment: When you say prefetch to a "local cache file" do you mean an object in JavaScript, or do you mean write out the contents of the downloaded json to local storage somehow?